# Limit and L'hopital's Rule

Tags: limits, trigonometry, indeterminate-forms

How do you evaluate the following limit?
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x\sin^{-1}x}{x-\sin{x}}$$
When I is L'Hopital's rule twice, I get:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(x^2+2)\csc x}{(1-x^2)^{3/2}}$$
Which doesn't exits. If the limit DNE then can't use L'Hopital's rule.

So, how do I find this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x\sin^{-1}x}{x-\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}x\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1{\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1x$$

The first & the last limits are elementary and

for the second use [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion)

Comment: I was under the impression that the limit property lim[f(x)g(x)]=lim[f(x)]lim[g(x)] held only if the limits were finite not for DNE.

Comment: @Ashish, It held if at least one of them is non-zero finite

Answer (score 1):

$sin^{-1}(x)= x+{x^3\over 6}+O(x^3)$ implies that $xsin^{-1}(x)=x^2+{x^4\over 6}+O(x^4)$,

$sin(x)=x-{x^3\over 6}+O(x^3)$ implies that $x-sin(x)={x^3\over 6}+O(x^3)$ implies that the limit is

$lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{x^2+{x^4\over 6}+O(x^4)}\over{{x^3\over 6}+O(x^3)}}=+\infty.$

Comment: It doesn't exist https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_(x-%3E0)+(x+sin%5E(-1)(x))%2F(x+-+sin(x))

Comment: Your mathjax could use some help.